# Обратна связь в андройд приложении

Tags: android, javamail

Здравствуйте, господа!
Я не так давно начал разработку своего первого андройд приложения и у меня возникли трудности с обратной связью. Как сделать обратную связь в приложении, через заполнение отведенной формы (layout .yml) и естественно самого кода (activity .java)? 
Нужно, чтобы письмо отправлялось не используя посторонних приложений, то есть приходило на определенную почту с информацией заполненной по форме по нажатию кнопки "Отправить". Отправитель должен остаться анонимным, ответ ему придет на e-mail, который он вписал в письмо. Все довольно просто, но реализовать все ни как не получается.

Comment: что подразумевает под собой "Отправитель должен остаться анонимным"?

Comment: То есть, он не должен логинится. От неизвестного пользователя будет приходить письмо с  его e-mail адресом (это одно из полей заданной формы, то есть его e-mail адрес придет как обычный текст), на который он получит ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `Intent` с тэгом `ACTION_SEND`, заполняй его нужными данными из полей, которые заполнил пользователь, адрес отправки хардкодь на свой, и по `intent.startActivity` письмо уйдет. Хороший подробный пример можешь взглянуть [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112450/)

Comment: Да, все работает! Большое спасибо!

Comment: @BredBear, хорошо, если считаешь что ответ верен - пометь его галочкой